# How can I show that the function $ h(a)$ is continuous, if I don’t know it?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, numerical-methods

Prove the existence and unicity of the equation $e^x + x^3 + x + cos(x) = a$ for all
$a \in R$. If $g: R → R$ is the function that maps a real number a to the unique solution $x(a)$  of
$e^x + x^3 + x + cos(x) = a$, is $g$ continuous?.

Using Bolzano's theorem I have shown that the function has at least one solution. The uniqueness, I proved it by monotony, in fact, the function is strictly increasing, therefore, the function has a unique solution for $ a $ fixed, I also proved this by assuming two solutions and using Rolle's theorem.

But, that unique solution depends on $ a $, let's say $ x = x(a) $, now I need to show that $ x(a) $ is continuous.

Somebody could help me? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=e^x+x^3+x+\cos(x)$$

$ f $ is clearly continuous and differentiable at $ \Bbb R $ and

$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R)$$
$$\;f'(x)=e^x+3x^2+1-\sin(x)>0$$
because
$$e^x+3x^2>0 \text{ and } 1-\sin(x)\ge0$$

thus, $ f $ is a bijection from $ \Bbb R $ to $ (\lim_{-\infty}f,\lim_{+\infty}f)=\Bbb R$.
So
$$(\forall a\in \Bbb R)\;(\exists ! x\in \Bbb R)\;:\; f(x)=a$$
and

$g=f^{-1} :a\mapsto g(a)=x(a) $ is also a continuous bijection from R to R.

Comment: I don't quite understand the part $ \forall a \in R $, $ \exists ! x \in R $: $ f (x) = a $                                                                                               I saw it almost the same, with the difference that $g(x) = a$ and $x$ continually depends on $a$

Comment: because  $ f $ is a bijection.